# Flushing and updating a graph in matlibplot via X11 backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, x11

I'm trying to print a graph from a Python script on AWS Linux over SSH/Xming on my Windows machine. Everything works nicely if I use a blocking `plt.show()` - I can't, however, show the graph correctly when running in a loop without blocking. My sample code is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
while True:
  heatmap = sns.heatmap(df)
  plt.show(block=False)
  time.sleep(10)
```

This setup (without the first two lines) works smoothly in Windows with Anaconda and IPyhon - I get an alternating plot and sleep. I'm getting no output this way with Linux though.

Comment: Using `plt.show()` with `agg` backend makes no sense, since `agg` does not produce any interactive graphics on screen.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. As I mentioned though, I am getting the output correctly as long as I use a blocking `plt.show()`...

Comment: That's weird. I could imagine that once one finds out why something is shown even though it shouldn't that will directly lead to why it then doesn't work in a loop. For that I think a lot more information about the setup are needed.